# Android: Intercept touch gesture handling from the parent to the child view

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

So I have the following view structure:

- LinearLayout

  - HorizontalScrollView
  - Other Child Views

The parent LinearLayout is clickable has a custom selector (changes color when pressed). I want to be able to touch the HorizontalScrollView within the LinearLayout and still handle the touch in the LinearLayout as long as it is not a scroll motion. If I do a scroll motion then the HorizontalScrollView should intercept the gesture and cancel the touch for the LinearLayout. Basically, I want to be able to intercept the gesture from a child view as opposed from the parent which is the standard.

I have tried to handle the MotionEvent manually by creating extension classes that do the following:

**LinearLayout**

```
public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    // Handle the motion event even if a child returned true for OnTouchEvent
    base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
    return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

**HorizontalScrollView**

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        _intialXPos = e.GetX();
    }

    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
    {
        float xDifference = Math.Abs(e.GetX() - _intialXPos);
        if (xDifference > _touchSlop)
        {
            // Prevent the parent OnInterceptTouchEvent from being called, thus it will no longer be able to handle motion events for this gesture
            Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    }

    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}
```

This almost worked. When I touch the HorizontalScrollView, the LinearLayout shows the pressed state UI and activates when the click is completed. If I touch and scroll the HorizontalScrollView then scrolling works. When I let go of the scroll, the click handler for the LinearLayout does not fire because it was intercepted. But the problem is that before I start scrolling the LinearLayout changes to the pressed state and it does not reset even after the gesture is completed. In my additional attempt to try to manually cancel the gesture for the LinearLayout I kept running into other issues. Additionally, the LinearyLayout has other buttons inside it which when clicked should not allow the parent LinearLayout to display the pressed state. Any suggestions? Is there a set pattern for intercepting touch events from a child? I'm sure it is possible if both classes know about each other, but I am trying to avoid coupling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following work for me for all cases:

**InterceptableLinearLayout**

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    bool dispatched = base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    // Handle the motion event even if a child returns true in OnTouchEvent
    // The MotionEvent may have been canceled by the child view
    base.OnTouchEvent(e);

    return dispatched;
}

public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    // We are calling OnTouchEvent manually, if OnTouchEvent propagates back to this layout do nothing as it was already handled.
    return true;
}
```

**InterceptCapableChildView**

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    bool handledTouch = base.OnTouchEvent(e);

    if ([Meets Condition to Intercept Gesture])
    {
        // If we are inside an interceptable viewgroup, intercept the motionevent by sending the cancel action to the parent
        e.Action = MotionEventActions.Cancel;
    }

    return handledTouch;
}
```